# Split Lucene index files without reindexing

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Is there a way to generate separate index files from a single one based on some sort of rule without reindexing the documents again?

The original index contains none-stored fields which means I can't read documents and add them to the destination index.

One option mentioned in SO is to clone the index into many and then delete the documents that don't belong to that index. I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> One option mentioned in SO is to clone the index into many and then delete the documents that don't belong to that index. I'm looking for a better solution.

What's wrong with this solution?  This strikes me as a very clean solution, involving just a few lines of code.

UPDATE:

Regarding the scenario where you have a 100G index, wanting to split 500 times, try this: for every subset of documents that you want to carve out of the index, create hard links to the source index, open the linked index and delete the documents that don't belong to that index.  If you're on Linux, hard linking the directory can be done by:

```
cp -lrp myindex myindex.copy
```

This can be done as many times as you need to and the links do not consume any disk space.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, but think about doing this when your index is 100Gigs and you want to split it into 500 different ones. Just run the scenario through your mind in terms of time and space needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question first when searching for a solution to my problem, so I will leave my solution here for future generations. In my case, I needed to split my index along specific lines, not arbitrarily down the middle or into thirds or what have you. This is a C# solution using Lucene 3.0.3.

My app's index is over 300GB in size, which was becoming a little unmanageable. Each document in the index is associated to one of the manufacturing plants that uses the app. There is no business reason that one plant would ever search for another plant's data, so I needed to cleanly divide the index along those lines. Here's the code I wrote to do so:

```
var distinctPlantIDs = databaseRepo.GetDistinctPlantIDs();
var sourceDir = GetOldIndexDir();
foreach (var plantID in distinctPlantIDs)
{
    var query = new TermQuery(new Term("PlantID", plantID.ToString()));
    var targetDir = GetNewIndexDirForPlant(plantID); //returns a unique directory where this plant's index will go

    //read each plant's documents and write them to the new index
    using (var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET))
    using (var sourceSearcher = new IndexSearcher(sourceDir, true))
    using (var destWriter = new IndexWriter(targetDir, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
    {
        var numHits = sourceSearcher.DocFreq(query.Term);
        if (numHits <= 0) continue;
        var hits = sourceSearcher.Search(query, numHits).ScoreDocs;
        foreach (var hit in hits)
        {
            var doc = sourceSearcher.Doc(hit.Doc);
            destWriter.AddDocument(doc);
        }
        destWriter.Optimize();
        destWriter.Commit();
    }

    //delete the documents out of the old index
    using (var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET))
    using (var sourceWriter = new IndexWriter(sourceIndexDir, analyzer, false, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
    {
        sourceWriter.DeleteDocuments(query);
        sourceWriter.Commit();
    }
}
```

That part that deletes the records out of the old index is there because in my case, one plant's records took up the majority of the index (over 2/3rds). So in my real version there is some extra code to do that plant last, and instead of splitting it out like the others it will optimize the remaining index (which is just that plant) and then move it to its new directory.

Anyway, hope this helps someone out there.